# Is there a way to mask CommandText of a VB.Net SQLCommand so it does not show in the SQL Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am inserting data from my application to an SQL Server 2008 R2 Database and would like to find a way to mask the pass-phrase so that it is not readable when tracing in SQL Profiler. below is a sample of my code.

```
Sub GetClientCreditTable(ByVal cId As String, ByVal cdnum As String)
    Dim oSQL As New SqlCommand
    Dim cText As String = String.Empty
    cText =
        <String>
            INSERT INTO ENCRTEST CDNUM,CLID VALUES('<%= cId %>', ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('*****', '<%= cdnum %>'))
        </String>
    With oSQL
        .Connection = New SqlConnection(oMain.ConnectString())
        .Connection.Open()
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = cText
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you not encrypt the value in VB.NET, and insert the result into your database, rather than using the database to do it?

Comment: @Jay: uhm, nope.  That would kind of defeat the whole point of sql profiler.

Comment: If you can't trust your admins, I'd say you have deeper issues.